# Generating Bezier Control Points for an object

Tags: opengl, surface, bezier

I'm trying to draw objects using Bezier surfaces with openGL's evaluators. I am struggling with defining the control points for my objects. Can anyone please suggest ways to get the control points for an object? Is there some program that I can use to design my object then import the control points into a file that I can use in my application?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.blender.org/

You can use Blender to create an object. It can store the points to a file in several formats.

It is a complicated program, but there are many video tutorials you get you started.

This is a beginner tutorial.
http://www.ibiblio.org/bvidtute/contrib/interface.avi

Here is a list of more tutorials.
http://www.ibiblio.org/bvidtute/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have another question though, in my appliction I only deal with control points (because I'm using the evaluators) but most file formats that I looked up (.OBJ for example) use faces and normals to define the object in addition to the object's vectors. So is there any specific file format that defines an object based on its vectors only?

Comment: Just because and .obj file contains normals and faces doesn't mean you need to use them. Just read the points and ignore the rest. It shouldn't be hard to write a script that takes an .obj file and removes everything except the points if you think that would be easier than reading an .obj file in your openGL program.

Comment: Btw, Blender just happens to be the only 3D modeler I've uses. There are many more. If your at a school, there might be a machine with a commercial 3D modeler kicking around somewhere. Here's a list of some more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_computer_graphics_software